# How to solve under-baked cookie centers?

Tags: cookies

I've made 3 batches of [this recipe](http://pinchofyum.com/the-best-soft-chocolate-chip-cookies) for "The Best Soft Chocolate Chip Cookies" but I can't figure out how to keep them soft *and* have them fully baked.

I baked the batches at 350 degrees with the following variations:

1. Exactly like the recipe, baked 10 minutes. Under-baked centers.
2. Made with browned butter. Baked 16 minutes. Fully cooked centers, but not soft.
3. Made with browned butter and refrigerated dough. Baked 13 minutes. Slightly under-baked centers.

Any suggestions? I'm not attached to the recipe, so if someone wants to recommend a totally different one, I'm listening.

Comment: Have you checked your oven temperature with an oven thermometer? It's possible that your oven is cool.

Comment: "refrigerated dough" is really common advice in cookies, have you tried more time variations from refrigerated?

Comment: @Catija - I think my oven does run cool. Is this why the outsides are finishing before the insides do?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that underbaked centers and browning exteriors is a sign your oven is running hot, but I'm not certain.

Comment: @rumtscho - I have not. Having seen/touched all the variations, I don't think 16-minute cookies from refrigerated dough would be any softer than the room-temp dough 16-minute cookies.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Catija completely. Your oven may be running too hot. If the outside of the cookie is 'cooking' more quickly, or sooner than the middle, then your oven is too hot. Trying backing the temperature down 30-40F and see how you fair. Going to a hotter oven, would exacerbate the situation, since the outside would be crunchy and set, while the inside raw.